# Creating vertical space between JLabels not going as expected

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to create a vertical space between JLabels. This is my code:

```
    JPanel label = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    label.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(50));
    label.add(label1);
    label.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(50));
    label.add(label2);
    label.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(50));
    label.add(label3);
    label.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(50));
    label.add(label4);
```

I want to have the equal vertical space between each `JLabel`, however, it gets weird when I adjust the  `Box.createHorizontalStrut(50)` Does anyone know why? The FlowLayout is done to position the JLabels to the left of the panel. In accordance with this, I want to position some of the JLabels in the center (hence the horizontal movement), is there another way to do it by the `FlowLayout`?

Thanks.

Comment: Flow layout is not the best choice for this.  If your need are simple, try BoxLayout or GridLayout.  (I also suggest you tag this post with `Swing` to get the right people to see it.)

Comment: The usuall case for `FlowLayout` is to place your components in a row. Use `GridBagLayout` for maximum customization. Also you can use some non-standard layouts. For example [MIG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/) or [Form Layout](http://manual.openestate.org/extern/forms-1.2.1/tutorial/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create a vertical space between JLabels

Then you should probably use a `BoxLayout`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for working examples.

> The FlowLayout is done to position the JLabels to the left of the panel. In accordance with this

Then you can use `setAlignmentX(0.0f)` on each of the labels. The BoxLayout will then align the labels to the left.

> I want to position some of the JLabels in the center

I believe this is the default value for the alignment of the label (each component is different) so you don't have to do anything. But if you want to make sure you can always use `setAlignment(0.5f)` on the label.